# Microsoft.PointOfService library

Tags: hardware, point-of-sale, pos-for-.net

I am going to use Microsoft.pointofservice library to communicate with point of sale hardwares. There isn't much documented by microsoft about this library. So before i spend my and other 5 developers time on this would like to get review of this libray if any one has ever used it.

Please suggest there are any other way to communicate with hardwares in unified way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used part of it briefly to speak directly to a receipt printer, an Epson TM-88III. One oddity if I recall correctly is that the framework came with a setup utility that you use to globally register devices with the framework.

I can't speak for much of the library. But the POSPrinter class worked!